# symfony2 how to access app/Resources/img from browser?

Tags: image, symfony, accessible

I've got some project specific images that I don't want to include in any bundle. I'd like to have them accessible from twig layer. The question is: how can I publish them (I can see neither symlinks in web directory nor assetic config in my project). Any hint will be appreciated.

edit:
When I run

```
php app/console assets:install help
```

I get `Installing assets for XxxBundle into web/bundles/xxx`, but nothing happens for the app/Resources directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really don't want to put them in a bundle you can just place them directly in the web directory. E.g. `image.jpg` placed in `web/appImages/` can be displayed in a template using `img src="/appImages/image.jpg" />`.

Nevertheless "the Symfony way" encourages you to keep everything within bundles. If you don't want to have the Resources in one specific bundle where your code lives you can have a separate bundle specifically for the application-wide resources.

Comment: This explains why I couldn't find the way to publish app/Resources/img. Anyway, why is that directory is there, if nothing is published? It doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz it can be used to overwrite the bundles resources. For example the twig template for the errors or the translations. (see example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can publish items in the app/Resources/img by doing:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

from the root of the project.

That is where you place system wide libraries.